# Unable to load the requested file: helpers/json_output_helper.php codeiniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am working with rest api in codeigniter,whenever I hit any web service then i am getting following error:
`Unable to load the requested file: helpers/json_output_helper.php`

I tried following steps:

1) in controller i put following code

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('json_output');
}
```

2) in autoload.php i added following code

```php
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html','form','file','json_output');
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is helper code?

Comment: @JimitH.: Here is my helper code (exist in helper folder)

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


 function json_output($statusHeader,$response)
 {
  $ci =& get_instance();
  $ci->output->set_content_type('application/json');
  $ci->output->set_status_header($statusHeader);
  $ci->output->set_output(json_encode($response));
 }

Comment: did you save helper file name like this : json_output_helper.php? if not try it. and should be add in folder in application/helpers.

Comment: @ni3solanki: file saved and exist in helpers folder

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file `json_output_helper.php` to `json_output.php`.

still not working ?

Your direcory migth not be accesible to change permission to 777 and it will work.

Comment: renaming helps. Thanks @JohnR